# vsftpd not in netstat

Tags: linux, ftps, vsftpd

I install vsftpd on Ubuntu mate. I do everything by this manual:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-use-ssl-tls-on-an-ubuntu-vps 
Result is the vsftpd is rununing as process "ps -aux", but if I write "netstat -ltpu" I haven't any ftp connetion in this list.
I don't find any solution on internet. I try reboot system, reinstall vsftpd.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick guess: vsftpd is runnig as root (or ftp user or something) and you are logged in as some other user. That means, the process name does not show up for you, because you are missing that right.

Try running

> sudo netstat --tcp -anp

for example.

Answer (score 0):

i had a error in config file. If I write command vsftpd as root, I get a message about error of config file. And vsftpd dont work corectli.